# Windows certificate manager imports a SHA256 root CA certificate as SHA1

Tags: tls, certificates, windows, certificate-authority

I generated the root CA test cert using: `makecert -a sha256 -n "CN=RootCATest" -r -sv RootCATest.pvk RootCATest.cer`

I've imported this root CA certificate on another machine (Win Server 2019, internal network) and it shows SHA256 in its properties, but the machine in question (Win Server 2016, in DMZ) shows SHA1 after import.

I need to generate SHA256 personal certificates from this root CA for testing TLS 1.2 communication between our applications. What should I do to resolve this issue? Is it a machine configuration problem?

Comment: Ugh, problem solved--user error. With a bunch of certs flying around in my test environment I got pretty mixed up and was actually importing an older SHA1 cert.

Comment: The hash used to sign _child_ certs matters for security, but the hash in the meaningless dummy self-signature on a root does not. Although it's prettier not to have "SHA-1" displayed in places that may alarm checklisters and other nonthinkers (which I see you have dealt with).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was created by user error.